# Resolving firebase related issue

Tags: android, firebase

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.

  > File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it. 
  >   Searched Location: 
  >   C:\Users\vinay rao\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication13\app\src\debug\google-services.json
  >   C:\Users\vinay rao\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication13\app\google-services.json
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 2.2 secs

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! What is your question exactly ? What went wrong is that you are missing a file. Please take a look to the [question documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

Hope you have got download **google-services.json** file from firebase console while creating your application.

Paste the **google-services.json** file to your project’s app folder. This step is very important as your project won’t build without this file.

like this
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your processed json file needs to be added to your  `app/` directory,

follow these steps in detail, https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin

Answer (score 0):

Go to [Google developers](https://developers.google.com/mobile/add) portal.
After filling all fields, you will be able to download `google-services.json` file. Then put `google-services.json` file to `app/` directory.